# Impossible to load the assembly that I added in reference, how to solve that?

Tags: wpf, .net-assembly

I referenced an assembly called Xenko.Core.Presentation.dll, that is in the same folder as all the other xenko's assemblies, but this one makes me crazy as I can't "load the assembly".

In the references, I can see that the path is correct, it has the right name and so on.

the error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException : 'Impossible to load the file or assembly Xenko.Core.Presentation, PublicKeyToken=null, or one of its dependencies. The specified file is not found.'
>
> FileNotFoundException : Impossible to load the file or assembly Xenko.Core.Presentation, PublicKeyToken=null, or one of its dependencies. The specified file is not found.

1. I looked at a thread that was saying he could not use a reference, but he was using a framework .NET 4.0 client profile, which is not my case, i'm on 4.7.2 and i can't go on .NET 4.0 just like them because my assemblies need the framework 4.7.2 if i understood correctly
2. then a colleague told me to use ILspy that is telling me which assemblies xenko.core.presentation.dll needs, I was missing a lot of assemblies but after adding them and rebuilding I was still getting the same issue

```
<UserControl x:Class="WorldView.WorldView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:xk="http://schemas.xenko.com/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:ehv="clr-namespace:Xenko.Assets.Presentation.AssetEditors.EntityHierarchyEditor.Views;assembly=Xenko.Assets.Presentation"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WorldView"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    
    <Grid>


        <ContentPresenter x:Name="SceneView" Visibility="{Binding LastException, Converter={xk:Chained {xk:ObjectToBool}, {xk:InvertBool}, {xk:VisibleOrCollapsed}}}">
            
        </ContentPresenter>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The error occurs on the first line:

> x:Class="WorldView.WorldView"

but the lines causing the errors are those with the ContentPresenter (as removing them makes my code working perfectly)

Any help would be a pleasure, thanks in advance

and Best regards =)

EDIT: i add the innerException
[image]

Comment: Translate your error message

Comment: oh yes my bad, it says: impossible to load the file or assembly Xenko.Core.Presentation, PublicKeyToken=null, or one of its dependencies. The specified file is not found. And then: FileNotFoundException: with the same text as before

Comment: Have you checked if there is an inner exception?  It might have more info on the missing module.

Comment: yes i checked, i didnt find anything useful, i'm gonna add it to the main post, maybe i missed something

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably a missing downstream dependency. That engine looks like it needs C++ runtimes, do you have the C++ features installed in VS?

Comment: do you mean installing the "development Desktop in C++" that we can see in "tools and functionnalities"? if it is that, then i have it installed, i tried checking everything and that gave me same error as before